# In react native, ANDROID,When keyboard is open, views goes also up, that disturb my design, or increasing height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-hooks

in react native Android, i don't want any effect on design of my views while opening or closing of keyboard

[disturbed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VPwT.jpg)[normal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qCZL.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<KeyboardAvoidingView>` component. It will work.
Link:- https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview